# Can tables::tabular be used on aggregated data

Tags: r, tabular

I'm trying to use tabular to produce pretty tables. I have aggregated data:

```
df<-data.frame(
  category=as.factor(c("cat1", "cat1", "cat2","cat2", "cat3")),
  color=as.factor(c("red","yellow", "orange", "red", "green")),
  counts = c(3,21, 24, 5, 97))
```

I want to produce a table that sums the 'counts' variable instead of counting the number of records.  If I do this:

```
tabular(category~(n=1), data=df)
```

produces:

```
category n
cat1     2
cat2     2
cat3     1
```

It seems like i need something like this:

```
tabular(category~(Sum=sum(counts)), data=df)
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in term2table(rows[[i]], cols[[j]], data, n) : 
  Argument 'sum(counts)' is not length 5
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

can you just use aggregate?

```
> aggregate(counts~category, df, sum)
  category counts
1     cat1     24
2     cat2     29
3     cat3     97
```

Comment: I'm using tabular for this project to create excel-looking tables in r markdown.  I've built several functions to create different layout tables. But one data set has aggregated data rather than individual records.  I'd like to use the same solution I built for this one dataset if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(counts = sum(counts))
# A tibble: 3 x 2    
#    category counts
#    <fctr>  <dbl>
#1     cat1     24
#2     cat2     29
#3     cat3     97
```